# How to package python script to send to others

Tags: python, package

I have a program that relies on several scripts, each script using several modules. The program can stand itself up on its own but if I send it to another computer, it will fail unless they have every dependency installed.

Is there any way to programatically install all the required modules so that it can be easily passed off to new users? I have tried to find tutorials on packaging the scripts as an exe file but the tutorials were either too confusing for me or failed.

Either way, I'm simply looking for an easy way to share my program and any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You could start here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/distributing/index.html#distributing-index

Comment: @scrappedcola Did I request offsite resources? I simply asked how to do a process in python I thought...

Comment: @JoeyB my apologies I apparently am having issues with reading comprehension today.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify your dependencies in the install_requires key of your setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='funniest',
      version='0.1',
      description='The funniest joke in the world',
      url='http://github.com/storborg/funniest',
      author='Flying Circus',
      author_email='flyingcircus@example.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['funniest'],
      install_requires=[
          'markdown',
      ],
      zip_safe=False)
```

In the example above, it will check/install the package markdown.
You might want to take a look at this howto:

http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html